# xDebug display lots of Notice: Undefined variable: messages?

Tags: php

I am using PHP 5.4.11 and I am using xDebug with it to help resolve errors.
I use the same form for creating a new entry and for editing an existing entry in a db table.

However, when I go to add a new record I see lots of warnings like:
Notice: Undefined variable: populate

But when I edit a file it is ok.
How can I deal with these?
Conor

Comment: Provide some code please

Answer (score 0):

Your form generation code contains references to some variables that are populated with values from the properties of the entry you are editing. For example, it might look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($name); ?>" />
```

When you are in edit mode `$name` contains the name of the entry being edited. However, when you are in add mode your code does not set `$name` *at all*, so PHP generates a warning when you try to use its value.

The solution is to make sure that you *always* assign values to these variables. When adding a new entry, assigning them a `null` value makes sense and will solve the problem.